# How to get complete list of changes between gazebo 7.1 and gazebo 11?

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I see each version of gazebo has its changelog in the repository, but those are only changes from the previous version. There are dozens of versions between gazebo 7.1 and Gazebo 11. I don't even know which belong to the evolution tree of Gazebo 11 and which are blind branched. If I want to upgrade my project developed for Gazebo 7.1 to be used with Gazebo 11, how to go about it systematically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24708/how-to-get-complete-list-of-changes-between-gazebo-7.1-and-gazebo-11?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All changes for every version are listed on the [Changelog](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/Changelog.md). You can assume that everything released into Gazebo 7, 8, 9 and 10 have gone into Gazebo 11.

The [Migration](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/Migration.md) notes have specific instructions about deprecated / removed APIs and their replacements.

I recommend you migrate one plugin at a time, searching through the migration notes for each function that fails to compile. Then once it compiles, run it, and if you experience any change of behavior, search for keywords through the changelog.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2